# Parameter values for saxon not getting in the xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I am not getting the parameter value (var in this case) into the XSLT when I tried to convert an XML document with saxon.

I got the following error in the terminal:

```
XPST0008: XPath syntax error at char 4 on line 8 in {$var}:
    Variable $var has not been declared
 Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

I tried the following in the terminal (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
java -jar saxon-9.1.0.8.jar -s:x.xml -xsl:x.xsl -o:x.txt var="name"
```

My XSL stylesheet (x.xsl) is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="//files">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$var"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML (x.xml) is:

```
<files>
 Var = 
</files>
```

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that I missed to give <xsl:param name="var"/> !!